# How to make my cannon fire continuously in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

In my game I can place a cannon on user player's location. I'm able to make the cannon fire once but can't make it repeat the firing process multiple times. I want the bullet to be reset at its original value after it travels a certain distance and repeat the firing process. I'm attaching my whole code below along with the part that places the cannon. Thank you for your help.

```
import pygame
import random
import math

pygame.font.init()

width = 900
height = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([width, height])

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1.png'), pygame.image.load('R2.png'), pygame.image.load('R3.png'),
             pygame.image.load('R4.png'), pygame.image.load('R5.png'), pygame.image.load('R6.png'),
             pygame.image.load('R7.png'), pygame.image.load('R8.png'), pygame.image.load('R9.png')]

walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1.png'), pygame.image.load('L2.png'), pygame.image.load('L3.png'),
            pygame.image.load('L4.png'), pygame.image.load('L5.png'), pygame.image.load('L6.png'),
            pygame.image.load('L7.png'), pygame.image.load('L8.png'), pygame.image.load('L9.png')]

char = pygame.image.load('standing.png')
bomb_pic = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('bomb.png'), (20, 20))
bomb_explosion = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('explosion1.png'), (40, 40))

pics = [bomb_pic, bomb_explosion]
shop = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("shop.png"), (60, 60))
boss = pygame.image.load("enemyboss.png")

player = [walkLeft, walkRight, char]

enemy_Left = [pygame.image.load('L1E.png'), pygame.image.load('L2E.png'), pygame.image.load('L3E.png'),
              pygame.image.load('L4E.png'), pygame.image.load('L5E.png'), pygame.image.load('L6E.png'),
              pygame.image.load('L7E.png'), pygame.image.load('L8E.png'), pygame.image.load('L9E.png')]
enemy_pic = pygame.image.load('L1E.png')

boss = pygame.image.load('pixel_monster.png')
cannon = pygame.image.load('tank_cannon.png')
bullet = pygame.image.load('bullet.png')

position = [60, 60]
x = 50  # same as position
y = 50  # same as position
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 5
isJump = False
jumpCount = 10
left = False
right = False
down = False
up = False
walkCount = 0
run_once = False

enemy_list = []

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
font_large = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 45)
items_font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 16)
font_small = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 18)
font_tiny = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 13)
font_verytiny =pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 9)

bombs = []
explosions = []

bag = {'bomb': 0, 'heal': 0, 'cannon': 0}

health = 100
base_health = 150
normal_enemies = []
kills = 0
cannon_list = []
bullet_list = []


class Button():
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text

    def draw(self, win, outline=None):

        # Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, outline, (self.x - 2, self.y - 2, self.width + 4, self.height + 4), 0)

        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height), 0)

        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 20)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
            win.blit(text, (
                self.x + (self.width / 2 - text.get_width() / 2), self.y + (self.height / 2 - text.get_height() / 2)))


def shop_run():
    bright_green = (0, 255, 0)
    green = (0, 200, 0)

    shop_bomb = Button((0, 200, 0), 820, 150, 70, 20, text="Bomb_b")
    shop_bomb.draw(screen)

    shop_heal = Button((0, 200, 0), 820, 120, 70, 20, text="Heal_h")
    shop_heal.draw(screen)

    shop_cannon = Button((0, 200, 0), 820, 180, 70, 20, text="Cannon_c")
    shop_cannon.draw(screen)


def walk():
    global walkCount
    global walkcount

    if walkCount + 1 >= 27:
        walkCount = 0

    if left:
        screen.blit(player[0][walkCount // 3], (x, y))
        walkCount += 1

    elif right:
        screen.blit(player[1][walkCount // 3], (x, y))
        walkCount += 1

    elif down:
        screen.blit(player[2], (x, y))
        walkcount = 0

    elif up:
        screen.blit(player[2], (x, y))
        walkcount = 0

    else:
        screen.blit(player[2], (x, y))
        walkCount = 0


def enemy_spawn(number_of_enemies):
    global normal_enemies
    global health
    global base_health
    global kills

    # for random_velocity in range(number_of_enemies):
    player_rect = pygame.Rect(x+20, y+20, 20, 20)
    for ne in range(number_of_enemies):
        random_velocity = random.uniform(0.3, 1.3)
        random_enemy_location_y = random.randrange(170, 470)
        random_enemy_location_x = random.randrange(800, 1000)
        normal_enemies.append([random_enemy_location_x, random_enemy_location_y, random_velocity])
        # print(normal_enemies[ne][0], normal_enemies[ne][1], normal_enemies[ne][2])

    for e in range(number_of_enemies):
        ex, ey, evel = normal_enemies[e]
        screen.blit(enemy_pic, (ex, ey))
        if ex > 75:
            normal_enemies[e][0] -= evel
        else:
            base_health -= 0.02

        normal_enemy_rect = pygame.Rect(ex, ey, 50, 50)

        if player_rect.colliderect(normal_enemy_rect):
            health -= 0.2  

        for j in reversed(range(len(explosions))):
            pos, end_time_2, hurt = explosions[j] 
            explosion_rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 20, 20)
            if explosion_rect.colliderect(normal_enemy_rect):
                normal_enemies.pop(e) 
                kills += 1   


def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount
    global font
    global font_small
    global font_tiny
    global font_verytiny
    global bag
    global items_font
    global enemy_list
    global pics
    global position
    global health
    global base_health
    global run_once
    global explosions
    global bullet_list

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    dx = []
    dy = []
    dist = []
    screen.fill([166, 166, 166])

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (220, 0, 0), (700, 500, 100, 100))
    # for five_enemies in range(5):
    #     random_enemy_location_y = random.randrange(170, 470)
    #     random_enemy_location_x = random.randrange(700, 840)
    #     enemy_list.append([random_enemy_location_x, random_enemy_location_y])

    # for enemies in range(5):
    #     screen.blit(enemy_Left[enemies], enemy_list[enemies])
    #     dx.append(position[0] - enemy_list[enemies][0])
    #     dy.append(position[1] - enemy_list[enemies][1])
    #     dist.append(math.hypot(dx[enemies], dy[enemies]))
    #     dx[enemies], dy[enemies] = dx[enemies] / dist[enemies], dy[enemies] / dist[enemies]

    #     enemy_list[enemies][0] += dx[enemies] * 2
    #     enemy_list[enemies][1] += dy[enemies] * 2


    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (70, 0, 220), (0, 120, 100, 400))  # main base
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (220, 0, 0), (50, 470, 5, -300))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 220, 0), (50, 470, 5, -base_health*2))
    screen.blit(font.render("B", True, (0, 0, 0)), (10, 200 + 40))
    screen.blit(font.render("A", True, (0, 0, 0)), (10, 235 + 40))
    screen.blit(font.render("S", True, (0, 0, 0)), (10, 270 + 40))
    screen.blit(font.render("E", True, (0, 0, 0)), (10, 305 + 40))

    enemy_spawn(5)
    # cannon_balls()


    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (800, 0, 100, 600))
    if x + char.get_width() < 60 and y + char.get_height() < 60:
        shop_run()

    screen.blit(shop, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(font_small.render("Shop", True, (0, 0, 0)), (5, 5))

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (220, 0, 0), (position[0] - 3, position[1], 50, 5))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 220, 0), (position[0] - 3, position[1], health/2, 5))

    screen.blit(font.render("Menu", True, (255, 255, 255)), (805, 10))
    screen.blit(items_font.render("Bombs: " + str(bag["bomb"]), True, (255, 255, 255)), (805, 550))
    screen.blit(items_font.render("Heal: " + str(bag["heal"]), True, (255, 255, 255)), (805, 570))
    screen.blit(items_font.render("Cannon: " + str(bag["cannon"]), True, (255, 255, 255)), (805, 530))

    # screen.blit(bullet, (450, 300))
    # screen.blit(bomb_explosion, (450, 300))
    # screen.blit(boss, (450, 300))

    walk()

    for i in reversed(range(len(bombs))):
        pos, end_time = bombs[i]
        if current_time > end_time:
            end_time_2 = end_time + 5000
            pos2 = (pos[0] - 10, pos[1] - 20)
            explosions.append((pos2, end_time_2, False))
            bombs.pop(i)
        else:
            screen.blit(pics[0], pos)

    for j in reversed(range(len(explosions))):
        pos, end_time_2, hurt = explosions[j]
        if current_time > end_time_2:
            explosions.pop(j)
        else:
            screen.blit(pics[1], pos)

            if not hurt:
                explosion_rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 20, 20)
                player_rect = pygame.Rect(x+20, y+20, 20, 20)
                if player_rect.colliderect(explosion_rect):
                    explosions[j] = (pos, end_time_2, True)
                    health -= 5
                    # print(health)
    for i in cannon_list:
        screen.blit(cannon, i)
    for j in bullet_list:
        screen.blit(bullet, j)
        j[0] += 3

    screen.blit(font_tiny.render("Health: " + str("{:.2f}".format(health)), True, (255, 255, 255)), (805, 60))
    screen.blit(font_verytiny.render("Base Health: " + str("{:.2f}".format(base_health)), True, (255, 255, 255)), (805, 90))
    screen.blit(font_tiny.render("Kills: " + str(kills), True, (255, 255, 255)), (805, 110))

    pygame.display.update()


def main():
    run = True
    pygame.display.set_caption("bomb-mania")

    global x
    global y
    global width
    global height
    global vel

    global left
    global right
    global down
    global up

    global walkCount

    global bomb_pic

    global font
    global bombs
    global explosions
    global position
    global health

    global kills
    global cannon_list
    global bullet_list

    while run:

        current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        redrawGameWindow()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()
                run = False

            shop_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 40, 40)
            player_rect = pygame.Rect(x+20, y+20, 20, 20)

            if player_rect.colliderect(shop_rect):
                buy = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                if buy[pygame.K_b]:
                    bag["bomb"] += 1
                    # print(bag["bomb"])
                if buy[pygame.K_h]:
                    bag["heal"] += 1

                if buy[pygame.K_c] and kills > 3:
                    kills -= 3
                    bag["cannon"] += 1 
                    # print(bag["cannon"])  

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and not player_rect.colliderect(shop_rect):
                if (event.key == pygame.K_SPACE or event.key == pygame.K_b) and bag["bomb"] >= 1:
                    current_time_2 = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                    pos = x + char.get_width() / 2, y + char.get_height() - 20
                    pos2 = ((x + char.get_width() / 2) - 10), (y + char.get_height() - 30)
                    end_time = current_time + 3000  # 3000 milliseconds = 3 seconds
                    bombs.append((pos, end_time))
                    bag["bomb"] -= 1

                if event.key == pygame.K_h and not player_rect.colliderect(shop_rect) and health < 90 and bag["heal"] >= 1:
                    health += 10
                    bag["heal"] -= 1 

                if event.key == pygame.K_c and not player_rect.colliderect(shop_rect):
                    print("reached")
                    cannon_list.append([x,y])
                    bullet_list.append([x,(y-20)])

        if health <= 0 or base_health <= 0:
            main_menu()
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel - 15:
            x -= vel
            position[0] -= vel
            left = True
            right = False
            down = False
            up = False
            # print(position)

        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 800 - vel - width:
            x += vel
            position[0] += vel
            left = False
            right = True
            down = False
            up = False
            # print(position)

        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 600 - height:
            y += vel
            position[1] += vel
            left = False
            right = False
            down = True
            up = False
            # print(position)

        elif keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > vel - 15:
            y -= vel
            position[1] -= vel
            left = False
            right = False
            down = False
            up = True
            # print(position)

        else:
            left = False
            right = False
            down = False
            up = False
            walkCount = 0

        clock.tick(FPS)
        pygame.display.flip()

def main_menu():
    global width
    global height
    global health
    global base_health
    global bag
    global position
    global x
    global y 
    global left
    global right
    global down
    global up
    global walkCount
    global normal_enemies
    global explosions
    global bombs
    global enemy_list
    global kills
    global cannon_list


    cannon_list =[]
    kills = 0
    enemy_list = []
    normal_enemies = []
    bombs = []
    explosions = []
    position = [60, 60]
    x = 50  # same as position
    y = 50  # same as position
    left = False
    right = False
    down = False
    up = False
    walkCount = 0

    enemy_vel = 2
    enemy_list = []
    bag["bomb"] = 0
    bag["heal"] =0
    health = 100
    base_health = 150
    pygame.display.set_caption("Main Menu")
    run = True
    bright_green = (0, 255, 0)
    green = (0, 200, 0)
    screen.fill((163, 163, 194))

    while run:
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()
                run = False

            if 400 + 100 > mouse[0] > 400 and 275 + 50 > mouse[1] > 275:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, bright_green, (400, 275, 100, 50))

                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    main()
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, (400, 275, 100, 50)) 

            screen.blit(font_large.render("Bomb-Mania", True, (255, 255, 255)), (325, 50)) 
            screen.blit(font.render("Play", True, (0, 0, 0)), (417, 285)) 


        pygame.display.flip() 
        clock.tick(FPS)       

main_menu()
```

The code below is the part that places the cannon.
This is part of main()

```
        if event.key == pygame.K_c and not player_rect.colliderect(shop_rect):
            print("reached")
            cannon_list.append([x,y])
            bullet_list.append([x,(y-20)])
```

This is part of redrawGameWindow()

```
for i in cannon_list:
    screen.blit(cannon, i)
for j in bullet_list:
    screen.blit(bullet, j)
    j[0] += 3
```

Edits

```
bullet_list.append([x,(y+25),0, 0])
```

The changes i"ve made to keep track of the distance traveled are given below

```
for i in cannon_list:
    screen.blit(cannon, i)
for j in bullet_list:
    screen.blit(bullet, (j[0], j[1]))
    j[3] = j[0]
    if j[0] == j[3]:
        j[0] += 3
        j[2] += 3
    if j[2] >= 100:
        j[0] = j[3]
```

Edits2
I'm implementing OOP, Please help me debug.

```
class Cannon():
    global cannon_list
    global bullet_list
    def __init__(self, x, y, track, old_x):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.track = track
        self.old_x = old_x

    def spawnBullet(self):
        for j in bullet_list:
            self.old_x = j[3]
            self.track = j[2]
            screen.blit(bullet, (j[0], j[1]))

    def moveBullet(self):
        if self.x <= self.track:
            self.x += 3
            self.track += 3

    def resetBullet(self):
        if self.x >= self.track:
            self.x = self.old_x

    def spawnCannon(self):
        for i in cannon_list:
            screen.blit(cannon, i)
```

Using class Cannon

```
for j in bullet_list:
    cannonsAndBullets = Cannon(j[0], j[1], j[2], j[0])
    cannonsAndBullets.spawnCannon()
    cannonsAndBullets.spawnBullet()
    cannonsAndBullets.moveBullet()
    cannonsAndBullets.resetBullet()
```

Answer (score 1):

You say that you want the canons bullet to travel a fixed distance and then refire.  What have you done to try to achieve that?

This appears to be the code that causes the bullet to move:

```
for j in bullet_list:
    screen.blit(bullet, j)
    j[0] += 3
```

There is nothing in here that stops it after it has travelled some specific distance or triggers a re-firing.

Your code would significantly benefit from object oriented restructuring and use of classes, in particular I would recommend that you make player, enemy, canon. bullet into classes. It not only cleans up the code but makes it simpler to keep track of the objects and all the respective state information that you need for each object.

For example for you question of re-firing after a certain distance has been traveled by the bullet. Right now the only information that you are keeping on the bullet is its position. To make it stop after a certain distance, you also need to know either its initial position or how far it has traveled since being fired. To re-fire you again need to know the canon it was fired from or possibly just its initial position if you just want to restart from the same place (assuming the canon is stationary). What about if the bullet hits something? Can the canon immediately re-fire, or does it have to wait for the same amount of time to elapse as if it had not hit anything and had to travel the full distance?  If later you want your canon to be rate limited or something rather than just only one existing bullet at a time you will need state information in the canon about firing rate and the last time it fired.

Structuring your elements as objects allows you to cleanly keep all of that specific state information together for each instance of each object. It makes it simpler for you to modify behaviour when you want to since the logic related to the objects can be contained and you know where it all is. That is very important as the code gets larger and more complicated, but is always good practice regardless.

It also generally makes it simpler for other to look at, understand your code when you are asking for assistance, or if you were to pass a project on to someone else.

Edit after OP modified question based on comments:

You edited your code and added this:

```
for j in bullet_list:
    screen.blit(bullet, (j[0], j[1]))
    j[3] = j[0]
    if j[0] == j[3]:
        j[0] += 3
        j[2] += 3
    if j[2] >= 100:
        j[0] = j[3]
```

Which does not make sense. The line `if j[0] == j[3]:` will always be true since in the line immediately before it you set `j[3] = j[0]`.
I think what you are trying to do is have this state information for initial position and distance traveled in the list along with the x,y position, and that `j[3]` is supposed to be the initial position and `j[2]` is the distance? This is not how I would do this at all, but ... You might try this instead:

```
bullet_list.append([x,(y+25),0, x])
```

and

```
for j in bullet_list:
    screen.blit(bullet, (j[0], j[1]))
    j[0] += 3
    j[2] += 3
    if j[2] >= 100:
        j[0] = j[3]
```

Again, you really should be using a class for this, not trying to keep the state as parts of a list.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'm still not very good at OOP but I am practicing. To answer your question on what I have tried to achieve the refire process, I have tried creating a variable ```traveled``` to keep track of the distance my bullet traveled but it didn't seem to work. I would appreciate some suggestions on how to implement my re-fire. Thank you.

Comment: @rishi As I said above, you need to know how far it has traveled in order to stop it. You said that you were keeping a `traveled` variable, but remember that is going to have to be a different variable for each bullet. Then you are going to have to compare each bullets traveled distance with whatever the max is. At that point you would have to delete that bullet and create a new one (starting at its starting point - the canon that shot this one) or reset the current bullets position to be back at its starting point. That requires you to know the canon that shot the bullet or the starting point

Comment: comment continued - The point here is that you need more state associated with the bullet than just its current position. That is best done by keeping it all together in a class. Even if you do not move the logic for the bullet into the class (which would be a good idea) you can at least use a class instance to keep all of its state information together.

Comment: I have made some changes to my question could you take a look and let me know what I am doing incorrectly.

Comment: Also I intend to create classes for my code later on once I'm sure it works. As I have said before, I'm still learning  OOP and find it a bit tricky, so I'll recreate this game with classes once I have created it with what I know.

Comment: @rishi The approach of adding classes after you get it working does not make sense. It is almost always the right approach to think about the data structures that you will need early on in designing a program. It will almost always make it much easier to writ the code and to make it work. Trying to do it after will almost certainly require you to make significant reworking of the code. The state information that I have mentioned is an example of that.  You do not even have to start with full OOP, you can start just using it to keep the per object state information together and organised!

Comment: I created a ```class Cannon```, Please help me debug it.

Comment: @rishi  added an edit to fix your list approach before your addition of the Canon class.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. The bullet and the cannon are just being blitted onto the screen.. the bullet isn't moving. I wonder what's wrong.